# How to solve for x when it's in a parentheses with an exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble remembering how to solve when you have an equation such as

$$0.3=(1-0.63x)^{5.26}$$

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to take the $5.26^{th}$ root. Can you proceed from hereon?

Comment: Is it $$0.3=(1-0.63)^{5.26}$$?

Comment: @Atmos friendly reminder that exponents longer than one character need to be enclosed in brackets.  `a^bcd` produces $a^bcd$ but `a^{bcd}` produces $a^{bcd}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can write $$0.3^{\frac{1}{5.26}}=1-0.63x$$

Answer (score 3):

From

$0.3=(1-0.63x)^{5.26}$

take to power $1/5.26$:

$0.3^{1/5.26}=1-0.63x$

and solve for $x$:

$x = (1 - 0.3^{1/5.26})/0.63 \simeq 0.324739$